# SQL Calculate Standard Deviation of count using window functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Calculate Standard Deviation of count of claims using window functions. I'm trying to find members whose standard deviation of count(ClaimNumber) is greater than 3. I do not want to use subqueries, is there a way to perform this using window functions? Unfortunately window functions are not allowed in where clause.

```
SELECT STDEV(COUNT(ClaimNumber)) OVER (ORDER BY Mbr_ID) AS STD_DEV
FROM myTable
WHERE Prod =91829
```

Comment: Have you considered using a CTE or subquery?

Comment: Can I avoid subquerie and use window functions for this use case?

Comment: Like you said, you can't use a windowed function in the `WHERE`, not directly anyway. You'll have to use a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Start with working code:

```
SELECT STDEV(cnt)
FROM (SELECT member_id, COUNT(ClaimNumber) as cnt
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Prod =91829 
      GROUP BY member_id
     ) m;
```

I cannot think of a sensible way to do this with window functions.